# can access a radio buttons checked state from anothe class in android

Tags: java, android, class

I have a 'MainActivity class', inside that i have the object of radio button. i have an another class 'classB' inside the 'MainActivity' how can i able to access radio buttons  checked state "RB1.isChecked()" from classB?

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity 
 { 
    public RadioButton RB1

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
     {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test_layout);

    RB1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButtonA);
     }



   public class classB extends BroadcastReceiver
      {

      }

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Make radio button static so you can access it in any other class.

```
public static RadioButton RB1;
```

In `classB` access Radiobutton using `MainActivity.RB1`

Answer (score 2):

The rb1 object is accessible with in your nested class so use it like this:

```
  rb1.isChecked()



   public class classB extends BroadcastReceiver
  {

        void doSomething(){
              if(rb1.isChecked()){

                         //place your code here
               }

  }
```

class B is an Non Static Inner class so it can access members of its enclosing class without any change:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Answer (score 0):

Both the above answers are correct even if you need to use the Class B else where you can use the sharedpreferences like this

```
SharedPreferences prefs1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

save the state of the radiobutton inside onCheckedChangeListener

onCheckedChange(boolean ischecked)
{


  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs1.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("confirm", isChecked);
        editor.commit();

}


and then you can access this anywhere 

boolean rbcheckedState=prefs1.getBoolean("confirm",true);
```